# Does expression's type must be same as conditional-expression in C?

Tags: c, conditional-operator

I write some codes as below while the function `DeleteNextNode` returns a type called `Position`:

```
return (the_checked_position->next == position_to_delete) ?
     DeleteNextNode(the_checked_list, the_checked_position) :
     printf("%s\n", "No such node in the list, delete failed."), NULL;
```

But the syntax checher plugin give a warning :`pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression ('Position' (aka 'struct Node *') and 'int')`

So does expression's type must be same as conditional-expression in C?

My English is very poor, so you can edit my question if necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.15` *Conditional operator* paragraph *3* says:

> One of the following shall hold for the second and third operands:
>
> > — both operands have arithmetic type;
> >
> > — both operands have the same structure or union type;
> >
> > — both operands have void type;
> >
> > — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
> >
> > — one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant; or
> >
> > — one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void.

a `struct Node *` and `int` do not match any of these criteria but it does not seem like that was your intention. I see that you are using the *comma operator* in this expression but since the *comma operator* has the [lowest precedence](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) it is really effectively this:

```
return ( operand 1 ? operand 2 : operand 3 ) , NULL;
```

so instead of the result of *operand 3* being `NULL` it is the return of `printf` which is `int` so most likely you really meant this for the third operand:

```
(printf("%s\n", "No such node in the list, delete failed."), NULL)
```

which would fit the above criteria and it probably what you originally intended. The fully corrected code would be this, with the added parenthesizes noted below the code:

```
return (the_checked_position->next == position_to_delete) ?
 DeleteNextNode(the_checked_list, the_checked_position) :
 ( printf("%s\n", "No such node in the list, delete failed."), NULL ) ;
 ^                                                                  ^
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can not understand what are you saying while your answer looks like missing some punctuations.

Comment: @acgtyrant I apologize for not responding sooner, I did not receive a comment notice. You are receiving an error because you need parenthesizes around `printf(..) , NULL` because of the way `,` works. I added the fully fixed code to my answer.

Comment: @acgtyrant The first part of my answer was answering the type requirement for the second and third argument to the *conditional operator*. The answer is unfortunately not simple.